# How to properly deallocate 2d array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, destructor

we just received the results of our final exam in C++. One of the questions was to write a simple representation of 2-dimensional matrix of `double`.
I had some points deduced at the destructor implementation with the note reading `invalid implementation` and no further information. Could you please tell me where I went wrong (if I did indeed go wrong).

This is the code I wrote:

```
~Matrix() {
   for (int i=0; i<_rows; i++) {
       for (int j=0; j<_cols; j++) {
          delete _arr[i][j];
        }
        delete _arr[i];
    }
    delete [] _arr;
}
```

The code for allocating the memory is pretty straight forward, I'll paste it to make things clearer, but the problematic part is in the code above.

```
Matrix(int rows, int cols) :
_arr(new double*[rows]), _rows(rows), _cols(cols)
{
    for (int i=0; i<_rows; i++) {
        _arr[i] = new double[_cols];
    }
}
```

Did they rightfully take away the points? Was my `dtor` implementation indeed invalid?

Comment: You made a complete mess of it. You should have one `delete[]` for each `new[]`.

Comment: If your 2d-matrix is of type `double` then `delete _arr[i][j];` is deleting a double is it not?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<double>> _arr;` and `: _arr(ysize, std::vector<double>(xsize))`

Answer (score 5):

The <s>`delete _arr[i][j]`</s> is wrong and shouldn't be there;         `delete _arr[i];` is also wrong - since this is an array that you allocated with `new []`, you need to use `delete [] _arr[i];`.

The rule of thumb is: a `delete` for each `new`; and a `delete[]` for each `new[]`.

Also the `delete`s of composites are to be executed in reverse order compared to the `new`s (which you did already).

Thus we get

```
~Matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++) {
        delete[] _arr[i];
    }
    delete[] _arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `new` then three `delete`. What's wrong should be obvious.

Besides, you have to use delete [] for both dimensions, since you have an array of double-array and then an array of double (double*[] and double[]), that lead you to :

```
~Matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++) {
        delete[] _arr[i];
    }
    delete[] _arr;
}
```

It's not necessary to destroy each value of the array of double, since they have'nt been created by a `new`

Moreover, a simplest implementation uses only one allocation :

```
Matrix(int rows, int cols) : _arr(new double[rows*cols]), _rows(rows), _cols(cols)
{
}

~Matrix() {
    delete[] _arr;
}
```

In this implementation, you should provide a correct accessor, since `matrix[i,j] = _arr[i+j*row]` or `matrix[i,j] = _arr[i*cols+j]` (depends on the way you arrange the values in the array).

Answer (score 0):

You should call `delete[]` for your every `new[]`, they should be pairing.

```
~Matrix() {
   for (int i=0; i<_rows; i++) {
        delete[] _arr[i];
    }
    delete [] _arr;
}
```